# Django raise not getting called

Tags: django, authentication, django-forms, django-views, django-login

```
    //forms.py :
```

//This is the forms part of my app.

```
    from django import forms
    from django.contrib.auth import (
    authenticate,
    login,
    get_user_model,
    logout,
    )

    User=get_user_model()

    class UserLoginForm(forms.Form):
        username=forms.CharField()
        password=forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)

        def clean(self):
            username=self.cleaned_data.get('username')
            password=self.cleaned_data.get('password')
            user=authenticate(username=username,password=password)
            if not user:
                raise forms.ValidationError("This user does not exist")

            if not user.check_password(password):
                raise forms.ValidationError("Incorrect password")

            if not user.is_active:
                raise forms.ValidationError("This user is no longer active")

            return super(UserLoginForm,self).clean()

   // views.py :
```

//views part where in , i used the UserLoginForm created in the form.

```
    from django.shortcuts import render
    from django.contrib.auth import (
    authenticate,
    login,
    get_user_model,
    logout,
    )
    from .forms import UserLoginForm

    def login_view(request):
        if request.method=='POST':
            form=UserLoginForm(request.POST or None)
            if form.is_valid():
                username=form.cleaned_data.get("username")
                password=form.cleaned_data.get("password")
                return render(request,"accounts/home.html")
        else:
            form=UserLoginForm()

        return render(request,"accounts/login.html",{"form":form})

    def register_view(request):
        return render(request,"form.html",{})

    def logout_view(request):
        return render(request,"form.html",{})


    //login.html :
```

//login.html which opens up as home page.

```
    <div>
    <form method='POST' action=''>{% csrf_token %}
    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username"/>
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Login"/>
    </form>
    </div>
```

There are no errors, but neither the raise errors show up on invalid //stuff nor the page redirects to home.html on valid user.  Please help me fix the problem. I am unable to find the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please `Rendering form error messages` to display the error messages...

```
<form method='POST' action=''>{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.non_field_errors }}
    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username"/>
```

Comment: Thanks @Raja Simon , i tried your method , it works for non-users but even the users are being denied access saying that the users doesn't exist.

Comment: @adityakuppa It should work. Create one test account and test it yourself?